# Replicating a MariaDB master to an Aurora slave. Possible?

Tags: mariadb, replication, amazon-aurora

Is it possible to replicate from a MariaDB master (external to AWS) to an AWS Aurora slave?

Before anyone asks me why would I want to do that, it's because my boss wants to do that way. I suggested the obvious MariaDB (external) master and MariaDB (AWS) slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using "standard" MySQL replication. In this chapter of the documentation is described how to do it. I hope it will be useful to you.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already done it a while ago and it worked. I used that documentation you mentioned.